# How to pass function in sort parameter in solr through drupal7 hooks

Tags: php, apache, solr, drupal-7

I want to pass function "map" in sort parameter from drupal using hooks.
My moto is to sort the listing after mapping fields.

My solr server query is:
http://local.host:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*%3A*&sort=map(is_site_web_id%2C2%2C2%2C1%2C0)+desc&fl=site%2Curl%2Clabel%2Cis_site_web_id&wt=json&indent=true

Its working fine on solr server.

I third below code in Drupal7:

```
function my_solr_module_apachesolr_index_document_build_node(ApacheSolrDocument $document, $entity, $env_id) {
    $document->setField('is_site_web_id', 1);

}

function my_solr_module_apachesolr_query_alter($query) {
    $query->addParam('fl', array('is_site_web_id'));
    //$query->addParam('bf', array('freshness' =>'map(is_site_web_id,2,2,1,0)'));
    $query->setSolrSort('is_site_web_id', 'asc');
    //$query->setSolrSort('map(is_site_web_id%2C2%2C2%2C1%2C0)', 'desc');
}

function  my_solr_module_apachesolr_query_prepare($query){
    $query->setAvailableSort('is_site_web_id', array('title' => t('Site Web ID'),'default' => 'asc',));
    //$query->setAvailableSort('is_site_web_id', "map(is_site_web_id,2,2,1,0)");
}
```

When I print the perameters from function "search" in Solr_Base_Query.php, I am getting sort:
 [sort] => is_site_web_id asc )

**I want to apply this condition in sorting in drupal7 using Hooks:**
**map(is_site_web_id,2,2,1,0)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied below code in my module function:

```
function my_solr_module_apachesolr_query_alter($query) {
    $query->addParam('fl', array('is_site_web_id'));
    $query->addParam('sort', array('is_site_web_id' =>'map(is_site_web_id,2,2,1,0) desc'));  
}
```

And its working fine. :)